# Axios in React Native - Cannot POST a Blob or File

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

I'm trying to post the raw data of a picture, using Axios, after taking it with `react-native-image-picker`.

I successfully generated a blob using this piece of code:

```js
const file = await fetch(response.uri);
const theBlob = await file.blob();
```

If I inspect the metadata of the blob it's all right: MIME type, size, and so on.

However, when I try to POST it using Axios, using:

```js
axios({
    method: "POST",
    url: "https://my-api-endpoint-api.example.org",
    data: theBlob,
});
```

what I receive on the API side is this strange JSON payload:

```json
{"_data":{"lastModified":0,"name":"rn_image_picker_lib_temp_77cb727c-5056-4cb9-8de1-dc5e13c673ec.jpg","size":1635688,"offset":0,"type":"image/jpeg","blobId":"83367ee6-fa11-4ae1-a1df-bf1fdf1d1f57","__collector":{}}}
```

The same code is working fine on React, and I have the same behavior trying with a `File` object instead of a `Blob` one.

I see in other answers that I could use something else than Axios, like `RNFetchBlob.fetch()`, but since I'm using shared functions between the React website and the React Native app, I'd really prefer an approach that allows me to use Axios and `Blob`s.

Is there some way to work around it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Updated answer

As pointed out by @T.J.Crowder in the comments, there is a cleaner approach that works around the issue of the React Native host environment, without touching anything else on the code.

It's enough to add this on the `index.js` file, before everything else:

```js
Blob.prototype[Symbol.toStringTag] = 'Blob'
File.prototype[Symbol.toStringTag] = 'File'
```

I leave my original answer here under since it's a working alternative if one doesn't want to mess up with the prototype.

### Original answer

The described behavior happens because the host environment of React Native does not handle the `Blob` type nicely: it will actually become just an object.

In fact, if you try to render `toString.call(new Blob())` in a component, you'll see `[object Blob]` in a browser, but `[object Object]` in React Native.

The matter is that the default `transformRequest` implementation of Axios will use exactly this method (`toString.call`) to check if you're passing a `Blob` or some generic object to it. If it sees you're passing a generic object, it applies a `JSON.stringify` to it, producing the strange JSON you're seeing POSTed.

This happens exactly here: https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/e9965bfafc82d8b42765705061b9ebe2d5532493/lib/defaults.js#L61
Actually, what happens here is that `utils.isBlob(data)` at line 48 returns false, since it really just applies toString on the value and checks if it is `[object Blob]`, which as described above is not the case.

The fastest workaround I see here, since you're sure you're passing a `Blob`, is just to override `transformRequest` with a function that just returns the data as it is, like this:

```js
axios({
    method: "POST",
    url: "https://my-api-endpoint-api.example.org",
    data: theBlob,
    transformRequest: (d) => d,
});
```

This will just make the request work.

Comment: Nit: *"...because the JavaScript engine of React Native does not handle the Blob type nicely..."* It's not the JavaScript engine, it's the host environment. `Blob` is a host-provided type. The JavaScript engine in React Native (JavaScriptCore usually) handles `Blob` just fine (for instance, in Safari, or any browser on iOS), provided the environment provides it correctly. If the behavior you describe is real, it's a truly massive error in the host environment provided by React Native, not the JavaScript engine.

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder I just edited my answer to better clarify this. I can assure you this is real, I just spend half a day on it :)

Comment: That's definitely better, but FWIW I would just call it the "host environment," this isn't a JavaScript issue. Or even more directly, "the Blob object provided by React Native..." I don't doubt you, I just don't have a setup to verify it. It's a shocking error. Have you reported it? (All they have to do is change the `Symbol.toStringTag` property Blob instances return.)

Comment: Unless the host environment is **really** messed up, you could fix this once and just use the same code you normally do. The fix is: `Blob.prototype[Symbol.toStringTag] = "Blob";`. Just do that once in your main script before you do anything else.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I can confirm it's working by adding this to my index.js file. I'm updating the answer with this approach, that I find cleaner, and reporting this as a Native issue. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure! Sorry you had to waste most of a day on this issue with the platform. I wonder if they have some reason for not having that there? Anyway, you'll sort it out in the bug report. Happy coding!

Comment: Saved my day thanks for the valuable solution... Adding transformRequest works fine

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Any way to do this in typescript?

Comment: @airowe - You could do [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIBsD2AjZBvAKGWOQG0BlATwFttN0A6MTcsKUAcwBU4OBdAPwAuZAGc2nANwEAvgQIB6BcgBymSCK4ALCKJRxRo4BxDUI4UcnjB0yUMjjJsUTAHc9UZOYBuwF6fMwJwgEOABXPUVlMB1kAAcXOOgwSjtLKAg4ABMAWkwQdEpJZBjgSzLkACsIoJhMTwAlTIQglTgwYG8IeTZUvDQsbAYE9XVKJIoaOkZmVnYQbl4+ZABeZAAiDBx14plkULAELXw5XvxkADEbCGGXZhSJqlp6JhYJBZ5+VY2r9Agd5B7A5HE4EIA). I'm shocked, though, if the React Native folks haven't fixed this yet. Is it still broken?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Not working with axios with the current server setup I'm uploading too. fetch works fine. Super odd.

Comment: @airowe - Well, it's axios-specific (their specific way of testing for `Blob`), so it makes sense it's just axios. I'm just really surprised that the React Native project hasn't fixed their `Blob` implementation. I wonder if anyone's reported the bug? :-) (One could argue that it's *also* an axios bug, `instanceof` would be more reliable than their `toString` thing.)

Comment: @airowe I reported it here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31824 but with no activity. Should we push it? :)

Answer (score 0):

I actually had this problem recently (using Expo SDK 43 on iPhone). I remember using axios over fetch because I had problems with uploading blobs with fetch in the past. But I tried it here and it just worked.

The context in this use case is downloading a giphy from url and then putting it on s3 with a signed request. Worked on both web and phone.

```
const blob = await fetch(
          giphyUrl
).then((res) => res.blob());
fetch(s3SignedPutRequest, { method: "PUT", body: blob });
```

Answer (score -2):

You can send file into server using `formData` through axios API like below :

```
const file = await fetch(response.uri);
const theBlob = await file.blob();
var formData = new FormData();
theBlob.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
theBlob.name = "file_name";
formData.append("file", theBlob);

axios.post('https://my-api-endpoint-api.example.org', formData, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
})
```

Comment: I actually need to send it as raw POST data, not as form data.